# Can I change the RD Web Access port or disable the IIS default website without affecting RDS?

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, iis, remote-desktop-services

We have a client running a Server 2008r2 RDS server. This server hosts the RD Web Access, RD Licensing, and RD Session host roles. The client also installed XAMP on the server to host an internal company portal. The client will not let us make any changes to the XAMP server or configuration and offloading XAMP onto another server is not an option. They do not use the RD Web Access portal at all and I don't think they even know it exists; they only connect manually using the Windows RDP client.

This coexistence doesn't affect the end users at all, but it does cause IIS to log errors in the event log every startup because it can't bind port 80. This is a minor inconvenience for us, as our monitoring agent logs a ticket every time this happens.

My investigation has so far turned up very little information, but my best options appear to be changing the port the IIS default website binds to any port other than 80, or to disable the default website entirely. However, I don't have a 2008r2 test environment to play with and I'm not certain how either of these changes would affect their RDS services; specifically, I don't know how tightly the session host or licensing server roles depend on the existence of a Web Access server.

Will there be any repercussions from me changing the IIS bind port or disabling the default website?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up changing the ports for RDS and confirmed that all applications and services still work. I just went from 80 to 81 and 443 to 444 and restarted the default website.

I don't like messing with a production system without knowing what will happen first, but in this case it worked out.

Comment: Thanks for being the guinea pig.  Now it's captured here forever! :)